# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dxof.lib dxguid.lib d3d9.lib, d3dx9.lib, winmm.lib'

Tags: visual-c++

lib `dxguid.lib` `d3d9.lib`, `d3dx9.lib`, `winmm.lib` in the linker and added the DirectX Sdk Directory so this should work but doesnt :(

I Keep getting this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dxof.lib dxguid.lib d3d9.lib, d3dx9.lib, winmm.lib'
```

Comment: Make sure it is d3dxof.lib in the given directory. (Ex: Make sure there's no x64/x86 folder above it)

Comment: That's a really long file name.  Careful with the double quotes and the commas.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit late, but maybe it can help someone.
Go to your project properties and in the Linker tab add in "Additional Library Directories" you Lib folder which is inside your SDK